# Making a directory inside a Docker container accessible from another container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have a Docker container named "data-container" which has a directory named /var/data. This directory is in fact an ObjectiveFS volume which is stored in AWS S3.
In addition, I have a second container named "app-container" which needs access to the /var/data directory in "data-container".

Is there a pure-Docker way of allowing "app-container" to read/write data to the directory in "data-container"? I could probably do that using NFS but I'm not sure that's the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple!

First create a data volume container

```
docker create -v /data --name mystore ubuntu /bin/true
```

Then you can bind this  "/data" mount to other container over the "--volumes-from" parameter like so:

```
docker run -d --volumes-from mystore --name db1 postgres
```

You find this description here in the Docker docs:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Chapter: Creating and mounting a data volume container

Comment: Thank you @Rene M. for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case, probably because /data is already used in the data container as the mount point for an ObjectiveFS volume. To clarify, when I run the data container without the `-v` option I see files under /data. When I run it with the `-v` option and use the `--volumes-from` option in the other container I can still see the files in the data container, however in the other container I see an empty directory at /data. Any idea what causes this?